# A newly discovered number: bleen!

Tags: code-golf, number

*"The Nobel Prize in mathematics was awarded to a California professor who has discovered a new number! The number is bleen, which he claims belongs between 6 and 7."*  --George Carlin

In this challenge, you will print all Integers, inclusive, within the given input range.  Print numbers ascending or descending according to their input order.  That is, for input `[n1, n2]`, print *ascending* if `n1 < n2`, *descending* if `n1 > n2`.

Since `bleen` is now an Integer number it may be used as input.  It must also be included in the output, between `6` and `7` where applicable.  Also note that `-bleen` exists between -7 and -6.

**Input**

Two Integers `[n1, n2]` in the range [-10, 10], inclusive, via your programming language's input of choice.

(Input may also contain `bleen` and `-bleen`!)

**Output**

Print all Integers starting at `n1` and ending with `n2`, including the newly discovered `bleen` between 6 and 7.  Output can be a range of character separated numbers in some form your language supports - that is, comma or space separated.  One trailing space of output is okay.

**Examples**

```
Input:  1 10
Output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 bleen 7 8 9 10 

Input:  -9 -4
Output: -9 -8 -7 -bleen -6 -5 -4

Input:  -8 bleen
Output: -8 -7 -bleen -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 bleen

Input:  9 1
Output: 9 8 7 bleen 6 5 4 3 2 1

Input:  2 -bleen
Output: 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -bleen

Input:  -bleen 0
Output: -bleen -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0

Input:  bleen bleen
Output: bleen

Input:  2 2
Output: 2
```

**Additional notes**

You may write a [program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419) and use any [standard method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447) of receiving input and providing output.

You may use any [programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2028), but [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are not allowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer – measured in *bytes* – wins.

Comment: Can output be prefixed and postfixed, i.e. `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Sure!

Comment: Is bleenteen between 16 and 17 also? (and is bleenty-bleen between bleenty-six and bleenty-seven?)

Comment: @Joffan ... and bleenty between 60 and 70?

Comment: @Adám - exactly, and so on...

Comment: @Joffan How much is (bleen + 7) / 2 ?

Comment: @Adám it is just possible that we are overthinking this :-)

Comment: According to #2 [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bleen), this is perfectly possible in a notation of base eleven, where 6₁₁ = 6₁₀, bleen₁₁ = 7₁₀, 7₁₁ = 8₁₀, 8₁₁ = 9₁₀, 9₁₁ = 10₁₀, 10₁₁ = 11₁₀.

Comment: (bleen₁₁ + 7₁₁) / 2 = bleen.555…₁₁ = 7.5₁₀

Comment: Newline separators are not allowed?

Comment: In mathematics there is only the Field's medal, no Nobel Prizes there....

Comment: @Graipher That's why you shouldn't rely on a comedian's standup bit as hard news ;)

Comment: @Geobits Wait, this new number is not real? But I just modified all the code I ever wrote to be in base 11...

Comment: @Graipher I never said it wasn't real. The part about the Nobel Prize probably wasn't though. Keep your modified code as-is :P

Comment: @Graipher: the Abel prize is a slightly closer analogue to the Nobel prize.

Comment: Was hoping for a bigger skit or context for Carlin and bleen. Here it is https://youtu.be/YHFLTb9Fp18?t=4m35s

Comment: So apparently [Derf](http://icarly.wikia.com/wiki/Derf) isn't the only newly established number... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, derf, 6, bleen, 7, 8, 9, 10

Comment: @PatrickRoberts There's also [Gird](https://xkcd.com/899/) between three and four: 1, 2, 3, gird, 4, 5, derf, 6, bleen, 7, 8, 9, 10

Answer (score 12):

## Python 3, <strike>132</strike> 130 bytes

```
r=round
bleen=6.1
m=1.08
a,b=eval(input())
d=1-2*(a>b)
print(*[[r(i/m),"-bleen"[i>0:]][i*i==49]for i in range(r(m*a),d+r(m*b),d)])
```

Takes input in the following example format:

```
-8, bleen
```

Comment: Does this work outside of `[-10,10]`?

Comment: @mbomb007 Nope.

Comment: Very ingenious solution with bleen and eval there, nice one. Another suggestion: use `bleen=7/m` for clearification without character penalty

Comment: @orlp is there a reason you named the variable bleen and not just a single digit char?

Comment: @muddyfish Yes, it's necessary for the `eval` to translate `bleen` into the correct value.

Comment: Ohh... Thats really clever!

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, <s>114</s> <s>100</s> 98 bytes

Input is an array with `[n1, n2]`. (If it must be two seperate arguments, +1 byte to change the function arg from `g` to `*g`. Bleen must be a string, `"bleen"`. Outputs an array of the range. Suggested by @Jordan with his (?) initial version granting -7 bytes, but I also golfed off 7 more after that.

[Try it online.](https://repl.it/CjNX)

```ruby
->g{a=*-10..-7,?-+b='bleen',*-6..6,b,*7..10;x,y=g.map{|v|a.index v}
y<x ?a[y..x].reverse: a[x..y]}
```

Original full program version that reads input from `ARGV`:

```ruby
b='bleen'
a=[*-10..-7,?-+b,*-6..6,b,*7..10].map &:to_s
x,y=$*.map{|v|a.index v}
puts y<x ?a[y..x].reverse: a[x..y]
```

Comment: If you make this a lambda you can get rid of `.map &:to_s` and save 6 bytes, and you can save one more by changing the initialization of `a` to `a=*-10..10;a[4,0]=?-+b;a[18,0]=b`.

Comment: I.e. `->*g{b='bleen';a=*-10..10;a[4,0]=?-+b;a[18,0]=b;x,y=g.map{|v|a.index v};puts y<x ?a[y..x].reverse: a[x..y]}`

Comment: @Jordan thanks. Didn't need to use the slicing trick to insert the bleen, though; my array composition is still shorter by about 1 byte.

Comment: Ah, I was counting the brackets; forgot you could omit them.

Comment: Should I upvote, or leave you at exactly 4k?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere lol fire away, it's going to break eventually anyhow

Answer (score 8):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 35 bytes

```
K++L\-P_J++`M7"bleen"`M}7TJ@LK}FxLK
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%2B%2BL%5C-P_J%2B%2B%60M7%22bleen%22%60M%7D7TJ%40LK%7DFxLK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%221%22%2C%2210%22%0A%22-9%22%2C%22-4%22%0A%22-8%22%2C%22bleen%22%0A%229%22%2C%221%22%0A%222%22%2C%22-bleen%22%0A%22-bleen%22%2C%220%22%0A%22bleen%22%2C%22bleen%22%0A%222%22%2C%222%22&debug=0)

The first part, i.e. `` K++L\-P_J++`M7"bleen"`M}7TJ ``, generates this array:

```
['-10', '-9', '-8', '-7', '-bleen', '-6', '-5', '-4', '-3', '-2', '-1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'bleen', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

and then stores it in `K`.

The second part, i.e. `@LK}FxLK`, finds the sublist indicated by the input.

Comment: I thought of such an approach too. Mure interesting if we had to take any int range...

Comment: ... and especially if we had to include bleenteen, and bleenty, etc.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 3, <s>157</s> <s>145</s> <s>123</s> <s>108</s> <s>115</s> <s>139</s> <s>161</s> <s>158</s> 153 bytes

Saved 22 thanks to Lynn. 17 saved thanks to shooqie. 3 saved thanks to ljeabmreosn. 5 saved thanks to Geoff Reedy.

```
a,b=eval(input())
s='-'
c='bleen'
d=a<b
l=list(map(str,range(-10,11)))[::[-1,1][d]]
x=l.insert
y=l.index
x(4,d*s+c)
x(18,(1^d)*s+c)
print(l[y(a):y(b)+1])
```

Input like `'-10', '8'`. Tips are welcome for a beginner.

Added 7 to account for `-bleen`. Added 15 to account for reversed input like `'8','-10'`. Added a large 21 to account for the reversed input signs for `bleen` vs `-bleen`.

Comment: `l.index('-6')` and `l.index('7')` should just be constants, no?

Comment: Good point, I'll add that in...

Comment: `l=[str(i)for i in range(-10,11)]` -> `l=list(map(str,range(-10,11)))`

Comment: Though I'm not sure why you need strings in the first place. `l=list(range(-10,11))` works as well

Comment: Lines 2, 4, 5 can be replaced with `for i in(4,18):l.insert(i,'bleen')`.

Comment: @shooqie The for loop is missing the negative sign at index 4. e.g. the list contains two elements of `'bleen'` rather than a `'-bleen','bleen'`

Comment: Does it work for input 'bleen' or '-bleen'?

Comment: @edc65 it should now, input should now be in string form rather than int form

Comment: @JustinTervay instead of `s=['-',' ']`, use `s='- '`

Comment: @JustinTervay: code doesn't work because you're looking for a number in a list, but it's a list of strings; use `l=list(range(-10,11))[::[-1,1][a<b]]` (which is shorter, too!)

Comment: @shooqie Works for me. My input is `'-8','8'`. Make sure you have the apostrophes. Your code won't work for cases where the input is `'bleen', 8`. Also using `s='- '` leaves a space in front of positive `bleen`, which isn't in the challenge and I'm picky. Note that my `s=['-','']`, the second part is just an empty string, not a space.

Comment: OK, I get it now. Still, having to include these apostrophes seems like a really dirty workaround to me.

Comment: @JustinTervay add `d=a<b` and replace `s=['-','']` with `s='-'`. Then replace `s[a>b]` with `d*s`, replace `[a<b]` with `[d]` and `s[a<b]` with `(1^d)*s`. That should save 3 bytes.

Comment: you can save a few bytes by adding `x=l.insert` and `y=l.index` and replacing those occurrences by the variables

Comment: This doesn't work for me with the input `'-2', '-9'` (outputs an empty list, because `'-2'<'-9' == True`)

Comment: @WorldSEnder good catch, unsure how to fix in a short/concise manner

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 141 bytes

```ruby
->*a{
l="bleen"
s=13
a,b=a.map{|n|2*n rescue s*(n<=>?b)}
b,a,r=a,b,1if b<a
o=(a..b).map{|n|n==s ?l:n==-s ??-+l:n/2}.uniq
puts r ?o.reverse: o}
```

### Ungolfed

```ruby
lambda do |*args|
  bleen = "bleen"
  subst = 13 # This will stand in for "bleen"

  a, b = args.map {|arg|
    begin
      # Double the number
      2 * arg
    rescue
      # It wasn't a number, so it's "bleen" or "-bleen"; replace it with 13 or -13
      subst * (arg <=> "b")
    end
  }

  if b < a
    # If the range isn't ascending, reverse it and remember that we did
    b, a, reverse = a, b, 1
  end

  # Step through the range, replacing 13 and -13 with "bleen" and "-bleen" and
  # halving everything else
  result = (a..b).map {|n|
    if n == subst
      bleen
    elsif n == -subst
      "-" + bleen
    else
      n / 2
    end
  }.uniq # Drop duplicates

  # Reverse the result if the range was descending
  puts reverse ? result.reverse : result
end
```

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, <s>239</s> 186 bytes

```
@set/ableen=1431655772,a=%1*3,b=%2*3,c=b-a^>^>31^|1
@for /l %%i in (%a%,%c%,%b%)do @((if %%i==20 echo bleen)&(if %%i==-20 echo -bleen)&set/aj=%%i%%3,k=%%i/3&cmd/cif %%j%%==0 echo %%k%%)
```

Works by looping from `3*%1` to `3*%3` and then dividing by three and printing the numbers with no remainder, however setting `bleen` to that magic number causes integer overflow and the value `20` is used instead. This is then printed out at the appropriate point in the loop.

Comment: @edc65 When was the last time I read a question correctly first time...

Comment: @edc65 oh, and I forgot `-bleen` too. Bah.

Comment: Tried it but no output. Usage example?

Comment: @edc65 `bleen.bat bleen -bleen` perhaps?

Comment: No output, as I said. Is it dos/windows bat language? I use Windows 10

Comment: @edc65 Works for me in both Windows XP and Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 158

Nice challenge, hard to golf. Probably the range methods used in Python and Ruby answers could score better even in JS.

```
(a,b)=>(c=x=>x<-6?x-1:x>6?x+1:1/x?x:x<'b'?-7:7,a=c(a),b=c(b),d=b>a?1:-1,a-=d,e=x=>x-7?x-(x>7):'bleen',[...Array(d*(b-a))].map((x=a+=d)=>x<0?'-'+e(-x):e(x)))
```

*Less golfed*

```
(a,b)=>(
  c=x=>x<-6?x-1:x>6?x+1:1/x?x:x<'b'?-7:7,
  a=c(a),b=c(b),
  d=b>a?1:-1,
  a-=d,
  e=x=>x-7?x-(x>7):'bleen',
  [...Array(d*(b-a))].map((x=a+=d)=>x<0?'-'+e(-x):e(x))
)
```

**Test**

```js
f=(a,b)=>(c=x=>x<-6?x-1:x>6?x+1:1/x?x:x<'b'?-7:7,a=c(a),b=c(b),d=b>a?1:-1,a-=d,e=x=>x-7?x-(x>7):'bleen',[...Array(d*(b-a))].map((x=a+=d)=>x<0?'-'+e(-x):e(x)))  

function go(){
  var a=A.value,b=B.value
  // make them numeric if possible
  a=isNaN(a)?a:+a
  b=isNaN(b)?b:+b
  
  O.textContent=f(a,b)
}  
go()
```

```html
A <select id=A onchange='go()'>
<option>-10<option>-9<option>-8<option>-7<option>-bleen<option>-6<option>-5<option>-4<option>-3<option>-2<option>-1<option>0
<option>1<option>2<option>3<option>4<option>5<option>6<option>bleen<option>7<option>8<option>9<option>10
</select>
B <select id=B onchange='go()'>
<option>-10<option>-9<option>-8<option>-7<option>-bleen<option>-6<option>-5<option>-4<option>-3<option>-2<option>-1<option>0
<option>1<option>2<option>3<option>4<option>5<option>6<option>bleen<option>7<option>8<option>9<option selected>10
</select>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: I think you missed -6.

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 2.2, 342 Bytes

```swift
func a(x:String,y:String){var k="bleen",a=Int(x) ?? (x==k ?(x==y ? -9:6):-6),b=Int(y) ?? (y==k ?6:-6),t=0,s=[Any](),f=Int(x)==nil ?x:"";if a>b{t=a;a=b;b=t};for i in a...b{if i==7 && a != 7{s.append(k)};s.append(i);if -i==7 && b != -7{s.append("-"+k)}};for v in t==0 ?s:s.reverse(){f+=" \(v)"};if Int(y)==nil&&b>0{f+=" \(y)"};print(x==y ?x:f)}
```

[Test this using IBM's Swift Sandbox](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57a3c19296ff73f744b74093)

**Ungolfed**

```swift
func bleen(x: String, y: String){
    var k = "bleen",
        a = Int(x) ?? (x == k ? (x == y ? -9 : 6) : -6),
        b = Int(y) ?? (y == k ? 6: -6),
        t = 0,
        s = [Any](),
        f = Int(x) == nil ? x : ""

    if a > b{
        t = a
        a = b
        b = t
    }

    for i in a...b{
        if i == 7 && a != 7{s.append(k)}
        s.append(i)
        if -i == 7 && b != -7{s.append("-" + k)}
    }

    if Int(y) == nil && b > 0{s.append(y)}

    for v in t == 0 ? s : s.reverse(){
        f+="\(v) "
    }

    print(x == y ? x : f)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 126 bytes

Input is in the form `-5, 'bleen'`

```
l=list(range(-10,11))
c='bleen'
s=l.insert
t=l.index
s(4,'-'+c)
s(18,c)
i,j=map(t,eval(input()))
d=1-2*(i<j)
print(l[i:j+d:d])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 271 bytes

```
int p(String w){if(w.contains("b"))return w.length()<6?7:-7;int i=Integer.decode(w);return i<-6?i-1:i>6?i+1:i;}void b(String s,String f){Integer l=p(s),r=p(f);for(r+=l<r?1:-1;l!=r;l-=l.compareTo(r))System.out.print(l==-7?"-bleen ":l==7?"bleen ":l+(l<-7?1:l<7?0:-1)+" ");}
```

Ungolfed with test cases:

```
class Bleen {
     static int p(String w) {
         if(w.contains("b"))
             return w.length() < 6 ? 7 : -7;
         int i = Integer.decode(w);
         return i < -6 ? i-1 : i>6 ? i+1 : i;
     }

     static void b(String s, String f) {
         Integer l = p(s), r = p(f);
         for(r += l<r ? 1 : -1; l != r; l -= l.compareTo(r))
             System.out.print(l == -7 ? "-bleen " : l == 7 ? "bleen ": l+(l < -7 ? 1 : l<7 ? 0 : -1)+" ");
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         b("1","10"); System.out.println();
         b("-9","-4"); System.out.println();
         b("-8", "bleen"); System.out.println();
         b("9", "1"); System.out.println();
         b("2", "-bleen"); System.out.println();
         b("-bleen", "0"); System.out.println();
         b("bleen", "bleen"); System.out.println();
         b("2", "2"); System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Call b(start, end). Because the parameters are strings, it takes a lot of space to convert those into ints. Essentially the program treats 7 & -7 as bleen and -bleen.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Was pretty hard to come up with something to golf you answer, but I did. ;) Your method `p` can be changed to the following to save 6 bytes: `int p(String w){int x=w.length(),i;if(x>3)return x<6?7:-7;i=Integer.decode(w);return i<-6?i-1:i>6?i+1:i;}`. Also, you might want to state this is *Java 7* and perhaps add [an ideone](https://ideone.com/MJ3fBz).

Comment: Also, I've been able to make a [shorter variant in Java 7](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88649/52210) based on [*@LeakyNun*'s approach](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87572/52210) of first creating the complete list.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 251 bytes

```
import java.util.*;String b(Object...a){String q="bleen",r="";List l=new ArrayList();int j=-10,i,z,y,t;while(j<11)l.add(j++);l.add(4,"-"+q);l.add(18,q);z=l.indexOf(a[0]);y=l.indexOf(b[1]);if(y<z){t=z;z=y;y=t;}for(i=z;i<=y;)r+=l.get(i++)+" ";return r;}
```

[Different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87572/52210) which is shorter than the already existing [Java 7 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88624/52210).
Also, it's unfortunate that the parameters are potentially not in order, which adds some bytes to swap them around.

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/RpkuFv)

```
import java.util.*;
class Main{
  static String b(Object... a){
    String q = "bleen",
           r = "";
    List l = new ArrayList();
    int j = -10, i, z, y, t;
    while(j < 11){
      l.add(j++);
    }
    l.add(4, "-"+q);
    l.add(18, q);
    z = l.indexOf(a[0]);
    y = l.indexOf(a[1]);
    if(y < z){
      t = z;
      z = y;
      y = t;
    }
    for(i = z; i <= y; ){
      r += l.get(i++) + " ";
    }
    return r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(b(1, 10));
    System.out.println(b(-9, -4));
    System.out.println(b(-8, "bleen"));
    System.out.println(b(9, 1));
    System.out.println(b(2, "-bleen"));
    System.out.println(b("-bleen", 0));
    System.out.println(b("bleen", "bleen"));
    System.out.println(b(2, 2));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 bleen 7 8 9 10 
-9 -8 -7 -bleen -6 -5 -4 
-8 -7 -bleen -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 bleen 
1 2 3 4 5 6 bleen 7 8 9 
-bleen -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 
-bleen -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 
bleen 
2
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 223 bytes

```
object B extends App{val b="bleen"
val L=((-10 to -7)++List(s"-$b")++(-6 to 6)++List(b)++(6 to 10)).map(""+_)
val Array(s,e)=args.map(L.indexOf(_))
println((if(s<=e)L.slice(s,e+1)else L.slice(e,s+1).reverse).mkString(" "))}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 178 bytes

```
 (s,e)=>{q='bleen';t=[];for(i=-10;i<11;i++)t.push(i);t.splice(4,0,'-'+q);t.splice(18,0,q);s=t.indexOf(s);e=t.indexOf(e);s>e&&t.reverse()&&(e=22-e)&&(s=22-s);return t.slice(s,e+1)}
```

[Try it](https://repl.it/Cjn1/2)

EDIT: Fix for reverse ordering.Thanks Patrick, missed this condition

Answer (score 2):

## **R**,  <strike>110</strike> 107 bytes

Thanks to Cyoce for golfing 3 bytes.

```
a=function(x,y){e=c(-10:-7,"-bleen",-6:6,"bleen",6:10)
b=function(d)which(e==as.character(d))
e[b(x):b(y)]}
```

Builds the whole list in order, picks out the relevant ones. Function in the middle named "b" seemed the easiest way to make that happen. Apply,etc

Comment: Is all that whitespace required?

Comment: No, and usually I wouldn't have had it. Thanks! Edit: I didn't even count much of it. Must have been half asleep.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (using external library) (343 bytes)

```
(a,b)=>{r="bleen";s="-"+r;c=d=>d==r?7:(d==s?-7:d);i=c(a);j=c(b);m=Math.min(i,j);n=Math.max(i,j);w=i<=j?_.RangeTo(i,j):_.RangeDown(i,Math.abs(j-i)+1);g=i<j?6:7;if(n>-7&&m<-6){w=w.InsertWhere("-bleen",x=>x==-7)}if(m<8&&n>6){w=w.InsertWhere("bleen",x=>x==g)}if(a==r||b==r){w=w.Where(x=>x!=7)}if(a==s||b==s){w=w.Where(x=>x!=-7)}return w.ToArray()}
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

## Python 2, 100 bytes

The first four lines generate the list `[-10, -9, -8, -7, 'bleen', -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'bleen', 7, 8, 9, 10]`. The next line gets input and stores it in `s` and `e`. The last two lines use `.index()` and list slicing notation to get the correct range.

```
a=range(-10,11)
b="bleen"
c=a.insert
c(17,b)
c(4,b)
s,e=eval(input())
d=a.index
print a[d(s):d(e)+1]
```

Works in the same way as Leaky Nun's answer but developed independently. Stole an input method from orlp.

## Ungolfed:

```
array = range(-10, 11)
array.insert(17, "bleen")
array.insert(4, "bleen")
start, end = eval(input())
print array[array.index(start):array.index(end) + 1]
```

Comment: This is incorrect - the number between `-7` and `-6` is `-bleen`, not `bleen`. Though we have found a new number, the basic rules of algebra must remain constant: `0` is the only number that is its own additive inverse, by virtue of being the additive identity element. Furthermore, `eval(input())` is just `input()` in Python 2.

Comment: @Mego oh, oops....